# entity framework insert only some columns

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I have a POCO class

```
public class Main
{
    public int ExstraColumn{ get; set; }
}
public class User : Main
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Age { get; set; }


}

public class News : Main
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ReadCount { get; set; }
}
```

now i want entity framework inserts only age column in user. But it gives invalid column name ExstraColumn

how to tell entity framework that ExstraColumn field is only special usage?

Comment: Define _special usage_ ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[NotMapped]` attribute in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

> Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database
>   mapping.